# React has no exported member

Tags: react-typescript

I am writing a component with react typescript, but when I am trying to use it, it kept saying there is no exported member
here is my component file:

```js
import type { FunctionComponent } from "react";

interface TitleProps{
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
}

const Title: FunctionComponent<TitleProps> = ({title, subtitle}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>  
      <h2>{subtitle}</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default Title;
```

and here is the page I tried to use this component:

```js
import { Title } from "@neuralbertatech/react";
import Head from "next/head";
import type { NextPage } from "next";


const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </Head>
      <main>
        <Title title="big title" subtitle="small title" />
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

here is the error:

```
'''
Module '"@neuralbertatech/react"' has no exported member 'Title'.ts(2305)
'''
```

and the Title.tsx is in this Module @neuralbertatech/react for sure.

Comment: You did a default export

Comment: So you need to import it without the brackets: import Title from "@neuralbertatech/react";